# How do I plot an equation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first time plotting a equation using javascript and this is what I got:

```
var j=10
var set=0.5
 function plotEquation() {
  Context.strokeStyle="black";  
  Context.beginPath();
  canvasContext.translate(canvas.width/2,(canvas.height-j)/2-set);
  for (var x = -canvas.width/2; x <= canvas.width; x += j) {
  var scale = canvas.width / j.x;
  Context.scale(scale, -scale);
  text.lineTo(x, eval(document.data.equation.value));
} Context.stroke();}
```

so far this will plot a line in the x and y graph depending on the equation but somehow I can't figure a better solution for this spaghetti code.

Comment: Are you saying the code shown works to produce the desired output, but you want to tidy it up? Step one in making it neater would be to fix the indenting and put the closing `}`s on their own lines. I wouldn't describe that as "spaghetti code", because it is neither complex nor tangled, it is a straightforward loop that is only hard to read because of the poor formatting.

Comment: What is your question? If it's just "Can I make my code better", post it on the Code Review Stack Exchange site. It would be off topic here.

Comment: Is my first time using this site and the code is not producing the desire output. e.g when I plot 3 is end up in negative -y axis instead of the positive axis. by the way I didn't add the drawing part of the graph which work fine

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain clearly (a) what is supposed to happen, and (b) what is actually happening. Also explain what the `document.data.equation.value` is.

Comment: Change -scale to scale, ie. Context.scale(scale, scale). -scale flips the axis. You'll also want to do transforms before adding to path as the current transform is used when adding to path. scale will accumulate inside the loop (and here also possibly alternates the axis which means it's not necessarily wrong using -scale, but it could be applied at the wrong point...) unless you reset if in the top of the code block (setTransform+identity). You can btw use setTransform for both translate and scale initially.

Comment: the  document.data.equation.value is. <input type="text" value="x" name="equation"/>. this program support to  plot a equation in the x and y axis using a quadratic graph. what actual happen this opposite of what I wants and what I said early, the number 3 end up in wrong axis (in -y instead of +y)